# How to make a div the same size as the div above in a Boostrap grid column?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

this is my first question here, be gentle, I just started learning those things :)

I'm working on building a practice page using only HTML, Sass and bootstrap-grid.css (so basically using only rows and columns, card classes are not included in the file, I styled them separately) and I encountered a probably very simple problem that keeps me awake at night.

I need to make all .card-text divs (the white background ones) the same witdh "visually" as the img above them, but simply resizing the .card-text divs or making them absolutely positioned doesn't seem as the right solution due do creating another problems, and I want to keep the .col- because of easy RWD outcomes. The .card-text and .card-img divs inherit the given width of the .col-, the images in  have to keep the right proportion  and because of the grey background of .card-img is the same as the whole section's background the problem lies only in .card-text (at least visually).

The column structure in a .row looks like this:

```
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-img">
            <img src="images/r1i1.jpg" alt="image">
          </div>
          <div class="card-text">
            <h6>Ebony & Ivory</h6>
            <h5>Branding</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

And so on (six columns) and the sccs for this section looks like this:

```
    .portfolio {
  background-color: $color-background;
  .card {
    background-color: $color-background;
    padding: 20px;
    .card-img {
      height: 300px;
      margin: 0 44px;
      overflow: hidden;
      img {
      vertical-align: bottom;
      height: 100%;
      }
    }
    .card-text {
      background-color: $color-body;
      padding-top: 29px;
      padding-bottom: 27px;
    }
    h5 {
      margin: 2px 0 0 0;
      font-weight: lighter;
      font-family: $font-decor;
      color: #737373;
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    h6 {
      font-family: $font-text;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 18px;
      margin: 0;
      color: #333333;
    }
  }
  .col {
    padding-top: 45px;
  }
}
```

Screenshots with inspection of the divs:

[.card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arX6J.jpg)

[.card-text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqfNk.jpg)

EDIT:

The scss styles that finally worked:

```
    .portfolio {
  background-color: $color-background;
  .card {
    background-color: $color-background;
    margin: 0 44px 50px 44px;
    .card-img {
      overflow: hidden;
      img {
      vertical-align: bottom;
      width: 100%;
      }
    }
    .card-text {
      background-color: $color-body;
      padding-top: 29px;
      padding-bottom: 27px;
      h5 {
        margin: 2px 0 0 0;
        font-weight: lighter;
        font-family: $font-decor;
        color: #737373;
        font-size: 14px;
      }
      h6 {
        font-family: $font-text;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 18px;
        margin: 0;
        color: #333333;
      }
    }  
  }
  .col {
    padding-top: 45px;
  }
}
```

So the problem was, of course, that I made a deadly sin by setting constant height to .card-img.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the same `margin: 0 44px` that you have added for the `.card-img` to your `.card-text` element and then add `width: 100%` to both the elements so that they occupy the full width of their parent div and you should get the equal width for both elements as you wanted.

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example of the above approach:

```css
html, body {margin: 0px; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
.portfolio {
  background-color: #222;
}
.portfolio .card {
  background-color: #222;
  padding: 20px;
}
.portfolio .card .card-img {
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 44px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.portfolio .card .card-img img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.portfolio .card .card-text {
  background-color: #333;
  padding-top: 29px;
  padding-bottom: 27px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 44px;
}
.portfolio .card h5 {
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: #737373;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.portfolio .card h6 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #333333;
}
.portfolio .col {
  padding-top: 45px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" /><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script><script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<section class="portfolio">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-img">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/240/360" alt="image">
      </div>
      <div class="card-text">
        <h6>Ebony & Ivory</h6>
        <h5>Branding</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you Andrew, I solved the problem with all of you guys ideas that pushed me to the right direction :)

Comment: upvoting doesn't work for me since I have less than 15 rep ;)

Answer (score 0):

- Set your img width to 100% rather than height.
- Remove padding from .card
- Remove margin from .card-img

Hope that works:)

Comment: Best way for answer the question is rewrite code and fixed it. Please edit answer and wait for responds.

Comment: Thank you Austin, I solved the problem with all of you guys ideas that pushed me to the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

Add certain width to `card-img` and then move `.card-text div` inside `card-img` and change the css styles for `card-img`.

I have modified your code and added it to the snippet.

Have a look once.

```css
.card {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}


 .card-img {
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0 44px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

img {
      width: 100%;
  }

.card-text {
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
    top: -4px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    padding-top: 29px;
    padding-bottom: 27px;
  }

 h5 {
    margin: 2px 0 0 0;
    font-weight: lighter;
    color: #737373;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
h6 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    color: #333333;
  }
.col {
  padding-top: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-img">
      <img src="https://p1.pxfuel.com/preview/844/972/952/suit-model-businessman-corporate-royalty-free-thumbnail.jpg" alt="image">
      <div class="card-text">
        <h6>Ebony & Ivory</h6>
        <h5>Branding</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Image Source: Google

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you Suraj, I solved the problem with all of you guys ideas that pushed me to the right direction :)